# A family of subsets with finite intersection property has finite character

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to prove that given a set $X$ the set $\mathfrak{C}$ whose elements are families of subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property has finite character.

To add more context, we say that a family of sets $\{F_i\}_{i \in I}$ has the finite intersection property if for every finite $J \subseteq I$ we have that $\bigcap_{j \in J} F_j \neq \emptyset$

And we say that a family of sets $\mathfrak{C}$ has finite character if it holds that: $Y \in \mathfrak{C} \Leftrightarrow \forall A \subseteq Y \text{ finite, } A \in \mathfrak{C}$

I'm having trouble proving that given a set $Y$ such that $\forall A \subseteq Y \text{ finite, } A \in \mathfrak{C}$, then $Y$ must be in $\mathfrak{C}$. I've tried that in this conditions every singleton of $Y$ must be in $\mathfrak{C}$ but I don't know how to conclude that $Y$ is in $\mathfrak{C}$. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In the first line you state that the elements of $\mathfrak C$ are families of subsets of $X$. But then in the sequel I encounter the expression $X\in\mathfrak C$. So it seems that notation $X$ is used in a different context there ($X$ is not a family of subsets of $X$). This is kind of disturbing/confusing.

Comment: You were right, I edited it to be $Y$ the name of an element of $\mathfrak{C}$ to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  $\mathcal F$ has FIP then it is immediate that every finite subcollection of $\mathcal F$ has FIP:$$\mathcal F\in\mathfrak C\implies\text{ all finite subsets of }\mathcal F\text{ are elements of }\mathfrak C$$

For the converse:

If $\mathcal F$ does not have FIP then this implies the existence of a finite subcollection $\mathcal F_0\subseteq\mathcal F$ such that $\bigcap\mathcal F_0=\varnothing$. But then $\mathcal F_0\notin\mathfrak C$ so we can state that:$$\mathcal F\notin\mathfrak C\implies\text{ finite subsets of }\mathcal F\text{ exists that are not in }\mathfrak C$$